# Laravel 5: remove default /?=value in url

Tags: url, laravel-5, controller, routes

I am using Laravel 5. In my Controller I am getting value from View like this method:

```
$params = array('' => Input::get("selected_category_id"));
```

then it showing in my log like this:

```
/api/zones/?=3
```

I try to modify which remove the single quote and equal symbol, like this:

```
$params = array(Input::get("selected_category_id"));
```

then it showing in my log like this:

```
/api/zones/?0=3
```

Can I set my url to be like this format:

```
/api/zones/3
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is this `/api/zones/?=3` ? Your url or input?
How does your **input** affects url (and why)?
If you want to do something with url you should provide some more info. For example `routes.php`, controller code and etc

Comment: after I click button submit, then in my Controller will get the value by using this `$params = array(Input::get("selected_category_id"));` . then my Controller will send the value to API. I am always checking my parameter and value passing correctly or not by using log. In my log show that the value pass using this url `/zones/api/?=3`. but what I want is, I want the url be like this format `/zones/api/3`. I dont want `?=` in my url

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your questions, you need to create a new route for it:

```
Route::post('/api/zones/{id}','YourController@processInput');
```

In the above route, replace YourController with the controller you are using to process the input and replace processInput with the method that actually processes it.

So, your controller would now have access to the category:

```
public function processInput(Request $request, $id)
{
   $categoryID = $id;
}
```